# Main Difference between popping and Peeking items in Stack<T> using C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, console, stack

I have simple console application written in C#. looking use of Pop and Peek methods and advantages.

```
Stack<string> movies = new Stack<string>();
        movies.Push("Fire & Dew");
        movies.Push("Hang Break");
        movies.Push("Naughty Monkey");
        movies.Push("Sabotage");


        Console.WriteLine("All Movies\n");
        foreach (string movie in movies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(movie);
        }
```

Comment: Do you only want to know the difference between Pop and Peek? Pop is good if you need to read and remove from the stack, while Peek will read without removing from the stack.

Answer (score 2):

`stack.Pop()`  -  Removes and returns the object at the top of the Stack.[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.pop(v=vs.110).aspx)

`stack.Peek()` - Returns the object at the top of the Stack without removing it.[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.peek(v=vs.110).aspx)

So if you need to just read the Top of the Stack you should use `Peek`.
If you need to go through the whole Stack you should use `Pop`.

Answer (score 0):

Stack is referred as Last-in-First-out collections and you can add or remove the element from the top of the stack. Adding element known as a Push an Item. 
              Removing element from the stack usually called Pop an item. How to use Stack class see the code.

In the following code I declared Stack. for simplicity, I represented each movie by a string containing it's title.
    I have added some more data by pushing item onto the stack individually.
    Some strange reason, the method to do this is called Push and after executing that line of code, there are four movies
    on it.

```
//Sabotage
//Naughty Monkey
//Hang Break
//Fire & Dew

Stack<string> movies = new Stack<string>();
        movies.Push("Fire & Dew");
        movies.Push("Hang Break");
        movies.Push("Naughty Monkey");
        movies.Push("Sabotage");

        //To display the data use foreach loop
        //You will notice that the foreach loop has displayed 
        //the movies in the reverse order to the order I put them on.
        Console.WriteLine("All Movies\n");
        foreach (string movie in movies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(movie);
        }

        // To access the top most string which is "Fire & Dew title" 
        //I can get it by Pop()

        //Data will be lost using Pop() but if you do not want to 
        //lose  data use Peek() instead

        //try first
        string topMovie = movies.Pop();

        //try later
        //string topMovie = movies.Peek();

        Console.WriteLine($"\nTop Movie is:{topMovie}");


        Console.WriteLine("\nAll Movies: After popping\n");

        foreach (string movie in movies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(movie);
        }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? You didn't even address `Peek`.

Comment: @JimMischel The poster of the question was a sock-puppet of this user. The purpose of this answer was never to be correct or informative.